# Notification on new user sign up

Tags: shopify

In Shopify, is it possible to receive an email notification when a new user signs up (just like I get a notification when an order is placed)?

I have checked under Settings > Notifications but could not find anything. If this is not a default option provided by Shopify, is it possible to implement this using any app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a webhook to send a notification to a particular URL when the Customer creation event gets fired. Go to your Shopify admin, click on Settings, then on Notifications, scroll down and click on Create a webhook. Once the popup shows, from the dropdown, choose Customer creation Event, JSON  or XML format and the url where you want to recieve the notification.

[image]

Once you have this setup, look for a webservice which reads webhooks and converts them into an email. Zapier would be a good nominee.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I saw the webhook option but could not figure out how to get an email notification. I will try Zapier.

Comment: Hi @alexandresaiz, sure...let me set up the webhook first and then I'll give it a try..I'll get in touch if I get stuck in setting it up on Zapier. Thanks again for the help.